# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\classes\user.php on line 39

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en PHP. Necesito implementar un System Login en un web. encontre uno en internet y lo adapte a mi proyecto. pero haciendo pruebas veo que cuando ingreso un usuario y contraseña incorrectas me da un error de:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in (ruta de aplicacion)/user.php on line 39

La linea 39 es la siguiente : if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1)

```
 <?php
    include('password.php');
    class User extends Password{

        private $_db;

        function __construct($db){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_db = $db;
        }

        private function get_user_hash($username){

            try {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
                $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

                return $stmt->fetch();

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }

        public function isValidUsername($username){
            if (strlen($username) < 3) return false;
            if (strlen($username) > 17) return false;
            if (!ctype_alnum($username)) return false;
            return true;
        }

        public function login($username,$password){
            if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) return false;
            if (strlen($password) < 3) return false;

            $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

            if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function logout(){
            session_destroy();
        }

        public function is_logged_in(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Por lo que leo en la documentacion, la funcion ``password_verify`` devuelve un valor booleano, y vos lo estas comparando con ``1``. Probá poner ``if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password'])){``

Comment: Es decir, eliminando  ``== 1`` de la linea

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el mismo error si lo coloco así: if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password'])){

      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
      return true;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `get_user_hash` retorna `$stmt->fetch();` el cual sera `false` cuando el `username` no existe.

Esto significa que la variable `$row` no será un `array` y al intentar accederla usando `$row['password']` en `if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1)` provocara la notificación:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in (ruta de aplicacion)/user.php on line 39

#### Solución:

Podrías modificar el método `login` de la siguiente forma:

```
    public function login($username,$password){
        if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) return false;
        if (strlen($password) < 3) return false;

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        // ACA - Controlamos el valor obtenido
        if (!$row) return false;

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            return true;
        }
    }
```