# Me sale este error cuando se loguea mal

Tags: php, login

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\Exact\login.php on line 18

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\Exact\login.php on line 18

```html
<?php

    session_start ();

    if ( isset ( $_SESSION [ 'user_id' ])) {
    header ( 'Location: /php-login/Exact/login.php' );
    }
    require  'database.php' ;

    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email =:email' );
    $records->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results=$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '' ;

    if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
        $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] = $results [ 'id' ];
        header ( "Location: /php-login" );
    } else {
        $message = 'Lo sentimos, esas credenciales no coinciden' ;
    }
}

?>

<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
```

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump` para ver el contenido de `$results`. El error menciona que esta variable no puede ser contada. Probablemente sea nula o algo más.

Comment: Gracias voy a probarlo

Comment: Funciona pero ahora me sale bool(false)

Comment: Ok, por eso no lo puedes contar, estas trayendo un booleano, lo que es true y false, no se puede contar. Prueba la solución de este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350768/notice-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-c-classes-user-p), ya que estas realizando mal el login

Comment: Vale, Gracias :D

Comment: Responde más tarde para saber si el problema fue solucionado o no.

Comment: es un clásico [según el manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) "El valor de retorno de esta función en caso de éxito depende del tipo de obtención. En todos los casos, se devuelve FALSE en caso de error." así que no le podes hacer un count si hubo error, podes usar en su lugar [`!empty($results)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) que verifica si (no) es false o array vacío

Comment: El !empty si que me funciona muschisimas gracias de verdad